# Can not resolve dependencies after upgrading to version 2.12

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Because I had some dependency issues, I decided to upgrade the Scala installation on my computer to version `2.12.0-M3`. I also ran `sbt -v`, after which many packages were downloaded.

However, when I try to refresh the following `build.sbt` file

```
name := """ScalaWeb"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.12.0-M3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.18"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

scalacOptions += "-Ylog-classpath"
```

I get the following errors:

```
    Error:Unresolved dependencies:
com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.12.0-M3;1.1.1: not found 
com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found
com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found 
 com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found
com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found
com.typesafe.play#play-ws_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found
com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found
com.typesafe.play#play-specs2_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found
com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.12.0-M3;2.4.6: not found
```

Version `2-12.0-M3` appeared in October 2015. It seems doubtful that all these packages are still incompatible.

How can I solve this issue?

**PS**

I was unable to use scala version `2.11.7` because I have the dependency

```
"org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.18"
```

Which, because of its dependencies, produces this issues:

```
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.11, _2.12.0-M3
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators _2.11, _2.12.0-M3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the SORMS author [is defining Scala library dependencies wrongly](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/58). As a result you have horrible transitive Scala dependencies for versions like `[2.10,2.12)`, so it will pick whatever latest Scala version was published, including in your case 2.12.0-M3 apparently.

Looking at the [POM of 0.3.18](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sorm-framework/sorm/0.3.18/sorm-0.3.18.pom) and the [POM of 0.3.19](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sorm-framework/sorm/0.3.19/sorm-0.3.19.pom), it seems that the later version uses (still wrong!!) `[2.10,2.11.999)`.

So I think you can solve your issue using these settings:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.19"
```

If not, you will have to [exclude the problematic transitive dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies) from SORM.

---

**Update:** The bug report also hints that the dependency you need to exclude is actually embrace. For example, using the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin, running `sbt dependency-dot` and inspecting the result I find:

```
"com.github.nikita-volkov:embrace:0.1.4" -> "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.0-M3"
```

which seems to be the origin of the evil.

Instead of excluding, I am now forcing a version of Scala:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.19",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value force() // !!
)
```

This worked for me.

Comment: I changed the versions, as you said. Furthermore, I am using `exclude` like this: `"org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.19" exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-xml")`. However, the issue with "scala-xml" is still present. I tried to follow the guidelines you linked to for using `exclude`. Is my code not correct?

Comment: I also tried `"org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.19" exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml")`

Comment: See my edit. You should probably force the scala-compiler version.